# Option to hide duplicate or closed questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, allowed-questions

Can we have an option to hide duplicate or closed questions? It would be easier to read that way.

Comment: Just ignore the pokemon go tag.  All done.

Comment: @Frank don't forget minecraft crash reports

Comment: Why down votes?

Comment: Votes work differently on meta. Votes show (dis)agreement with the topic. Your reputation will not be affected, and it's not a reflection on the quality of the question

Comment: @Bob2Chiv sorry for late reply, I know how meta works already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, but this is not going to happen.

Arqade is part of the Stack Exchange network, which is built on the idea of community moderation. You can see closed/on hold questions on the main pages and tabs because the idea is you might be able to moderate them in some way, usually by either voting, editing, flagging or even just requesting clarifications from the OP.

As a workaround, if you're that dead-set on not seeing closed/on-hold questions, you can use the advanced search features to view questions instead. Search by [closed:no and sort by 'active'](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=closed%3ano) to completely filter them out and get a near-equivalent view that the home page provides.

You can also hide an entire tag by adding it to your [ignore list](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) (and setting your preferences to hide ignored tags):

[image: Hide ignored tags]

---

And just while I'm here, here's a crash-course on closed questions & the moderation tools:

- **Closure is not a finite state**. A question that is clarified, reduced in scope, or otherwise edited in some way so as to make the close reason no longer valid can be reopened.

  - On the other side of the spectrum, a question that is unsalvagable will eventually be deleted (except for duplicates, which stick around to act as 'signposts' to the duplicate).
- You will unlock the [privileges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to vote to close/reopen at 3k reputation, and vote to delete (or undelete) at 10K. Until then, your best moderation tool is your votes.
- A question that is at -4 or lower will not appear on the front page of the site, so if something is really that bad/unsalvagable, you should vote it down.
- Don't forget your flags!

  - You can flag to suggest duplicates or closure, this places the question in the review queues (as well as alerting mods) so that higher reputation users can look at & action them)
  - Also flag for spam and abusive text/imagery. Enough spam flags will auto-delete the question and prevent the user account from posting again. *Don't bother voting to close spam, or attempting to edit out the spam links*, just flag and move on.
  - In cases where the stock flags do not apply, you can flag for moderator attention with a custom reason explaining the situation.

Check out the [Help Center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) for more info or if you get stuck :-)

Comment: Are you going to add [status-declined]?

Comment: @Alex - oh, if you insist :)

Comment: Robotnik, @Alex, Here is what I found *very* efficient: 
  
Just place the technical-issues tag in your ignored tags list, and select "Hide questions in your ignored tags" and you're done. This method will filter out about 60-80% of closed questions, alongside with some low-quality ones :)